# Checking if a function of a program attached in gdb inside gdb exits or not...and apply it in if condition

Tags: python, automation, gdb

I am new to gdb and stack overflow...I just wanted to ask if there is a way to determine whether a function inside a program that is attached to gdb exits or not and get a bool true or false value out of it? if it exists I want to put a  breakpoint on the function else just give an error?
currently, I am creating an automation script for gdb using python and wanted the catch the error if it tries to break a function which does not exits inside the program........

Comment: GDB does support 'going backwards' or otherwise termed 'reverse execution'. Have you taken a look at the python module for GDB pygdb2 ?

Comment: @Cibin Joseph     no ..but currently i am using a gdb module..by  ( import gdb ) and executing the gdb commands inside python using gdb.execute("break fun")...or something like that ...

Comment: Use the `next` command, run a parallel timer thread, if the seduce does not complete within X seconds then consider it not finished. ■ (also, include a [example] and capitalize the question properly.)